# How to highlight top line of ruby markup text (for copy+paste)?

Tags: html, markup

I am creating HTML pages with a base string and annotations on top of the base string's words and letters. Right now I'm using the **ruby, rb** and **rt** tags and I tried tables and divs too. It looks like this:

[image: text ruby markup]

Source:

```
<body>
<ruby>
<rb>新</rb><rt>しん</rt>
<rb>Brasil</rb><rt>ブラジル</rt>
<rb>1</rb><rt>いち</rt>
etc.
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to rewrite the HTML, so the output looks roughly the same, but at the same time allow highlighting only the small characters shown in yellow, without having to select the big letters with them (so that the selection can be copied to the clipboard)?

Right now, and with the simple table cell methods I tried, you are forced to highlight big letters with the small.

The picture makes the association look totally random, but the tricky part is that the markup has to line up centered with the corresponding "big" letters.

Comment: 'Sup? Overlapping div's with <sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.r { display: inline-block;  text-align: center;}
.ra { display: block;  font-size: 60%; }
</style>
<a class=r><span class=ra>しん</span>新</a>
<a class=r><span class=ra>ブラジル</span>Brasil</a>
<a class=r><span class=ra>いち</span>1</a>
```

On browsers that support ruby markup, the ruby annotations looks selectable and copyable to me. But on IE, when an annotation is selected, the distinctive background color used the browser extends down over the base texts as well, so it *looks* like you had selected both. If you do Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V then, you’ll see that only the annotation is copied. On Chrome, this problem does not exist: only the selected annotation is highlighted.

This could still be seen a problem. There is the perhaps more serious problem that Firefox does not support ruby markup.

The code I suggest above uses text-level markup with classes instead of ruby markup and styling that displays it in a ruby-like manner. I put the annotation *before* the annotated word, since then it is easy to place the annotation above the base text—without positioning, just by making the container element an inline block and the annotation a block inside it.

The markup is a bit messy, but this approach works widely across browsers. I suppose main problem is with `display: inline-block`, but it seems that in simple use like this, [support](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) exists even in old versions of IE (from IE 5.5).

Comment: Thanks, the code you showed is helpful since it works for many browsers. There was a simple way right under my nose to get the behavior I want: put all annotations in a table row, then all the base letter in the next row.

Comment: @6Heitor Chang, yes, that’s another approach and somewhat simpler, and even more cross-browser. A problem with it is that you cannot use it as such inline (inside a paragraph), and if there are many words, you need to divide the text into two or more rows in the table. The method I suggested is flexible in the sense that you can use it inline and without forced division into lines.